# C# Simplest way to join strings in a breadcrumb order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have `List<string>`:

"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"

What I would like a new list to be would be:

"Item1", "Item1/Item2", "Item1/Item2/Item3", "Item1/Item2/Item3/Item4"

I am drawing a blank on how to do this the simplest way possible.  I am doing this for breadcrumbs based off of the following:

```
var urlItems = Request.RawUrl.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to paul, here is my final solution:

```
var urlItems = Request.RawUrl.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var breadcrumbs = urlItems.Select((t, index) => string.Format("<li{0}><a href=\"/Gallery/{1}\">{2}</a></li>", (t == urlItems.Last() ? " active=\"active\"" : ""), string.Join("/", urlItems.Take(index + 1)), t)).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, the question seems clear and I provided code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string> { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };
        List<string> newList = new List<string>();

        for (var index = 1; index <= myList.Count(); index++)
        {
            newList.Add(string.Join("/", myList.Take(index)));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Linq:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"};
string item = "";
var list2 = list.Select(i =>
      { return item = (item == "") ? i : string.Join(@"/", item, i); }).ToList();
```